# How can I customize the Cryptographic Service Provider (Base CSP) in the Smart card subsystem architecture

Tags: windows, security, cryptography, smartcard

From microsoft documentation [image: Smart card sign-in flow] 

In steps **6** and **7** (**Kerberos SSP** <-> **CSP or Base CSP**): In essence, it exchanges a copy of the x.509 certificate (from a smart card) in the pre-authentication data field of the request and is signed by the private key.

I wonder if there is any method to customize CSP (Cryptographic Service Provider) so that **Kerberos SSP** can get x.509 certificate (self-created) without using smart card? Then from Kerberos SSP send the certificate to AD (active directory).

Link Microsoft documentation: 

**Certificate Requirements and Enumeration**: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/identity-protection/smart-cards/smart-card-certificate-requirements-and-enumeration

**Smart Card Architecture**: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/identity-protection/smart-cards/smart-card-architecture

Please let me know. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Kerberos doesn't care whether the certificate lives on a smart card or not. All it cares about is whether a handle to a certificate was passed to it. The act of getting the handle and passing it to Kerberos are two separate processes above. All of this can be accomplished by passing the credential handle to ACH within the SSPI functions.

Comment: @Steve  I found a example document from microsoft 「Getting a Certificate for Schannel」(Link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/secauthn/getting-a-certificate-for-schannel)  -- The example demonstrates opening a certificate store and locating a certificate that will be passed to the SSPI AcquireCredentialsHandle function. -- I wonder Is this is the same as method to user get a certificate and send to AD to passed authentication? -- Thanks in advance!

Comment: Functionally yes, that code would most likely work. The difference being that you pass the handle through a `SEC_WINNT_AUTH_IDENTITY_EX2` struct instead of an SChannel struct.

Comment: @Steve,Assuming I use the AcquireCredentialsHandle (Schannel) function, then in the Parameters(pAuthData) I got the SCHANNEL_CRED structure. This structure has the full information of a certificate because it called from the function「Getting a Certificate for Schannel」--- I would like to return to the topic is AcquireCredentialsHandle (kerberos) function,  I still haven't found a function API to opening a certificate store and locating a certificate that will be passed to the AcquireCredentialsHandle(kerberos)function, even though I understand it must be SEC_WINNT_AUTH_IDENTITY_EX2 struct.